# I want to filter out the last Number in String

Tags: java

My String is

> "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES={},
>   SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509170142065114105}}"

Here i want to filter out only **1509170142065114105** this string here 123 can be anything.

how can I do it ?

Comment: atleast show what approach you did, it didnt seems to be a tough logic, show your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex `.*(?:\\D|^)(\\d+).*` to get last number in the `String`.

**USE:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509170142065114105}}";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*(?:\\D|^)(\\d+).*", "$1"));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1509170142065114105
```

**DEMO:**

[Check here a working demo](https://ideone.com/6evlGB).

Answer (score 0):

A regex will work for you.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "{FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509170142065114105}}";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*=(\\d+).*", "$1"));
}
```

O/P :

```
1509170142065114105
```

Comment: can you suggest me for this String "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509180522720153332, 124=1509181140480153332}}"

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya what is the expected output?. 123=? or 124 = ?

Comment: I want output for list of 1509180522720153332  from this String

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya - Try this ==> `System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?=(\\d+).*", "$1"));`

Comment: I can see only one success entry 1509180522720153332  not second 1509181140480153332  . I want want both success entry in list of String

Answer (score 0):

If all your strings are of same format then you can use `lastIndexOf` and `substring`.

```
    String s = "{FAILED_ENTRIES={}, SUCCESS_ENTRIES={123=1509170142065114105}}";
    int lastEqualIndex = s.lastIndexOf("=");

    String lastNumber = s.substring(lastEqualIndex + 1, s.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(lastNumber);
```

Output `1509170142065114105`

If your sting formats can vary then the `regex` solutions posted by @Jordi Castilla should be better.